# Why does my python code not read the entire text file? The txt file weighs 3GB

Tags: python

This is the code:

```py
from datetime import date

f = open("POOL.PROD.IISOFENC.C522.EDMA.txt","r", encoding="cp1252")



resultado = open("resultado.txt","w")
fecha_actual = str(date.today())

for line in f:
    AuditoFechaLog = fecha_actual.replace("-","")
    ObjetoI = line[29:39]
    linea1 = AuditoFechaLog +  ObjetoI
    resultado.write(f"{linea1}\n")

resultado.close()
f.close()
```

I can't understand why you don't read it completely, any explanation or suggestion?

Maybe the problem is this error? I don't know

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ignacio.carrera\Desktop\Txt hincha\prueba.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in infile:
  File "C:\Users\ignacio.carrera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7118: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You never use `line` inside the loop, so the output file will just contain as many lines as the output, but all of them will just contain the date.

Comment: why do you think it isn't being read completely?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrvillaga because the source text has 346k lines and the result should be double more or less

Comment: and I'm having 15k lines

Comment: maybe this is te problem?

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7118: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: so you are getting an error? You **must** provide details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga look again the code

Comment: The error message means that the file is not valid CP1252 characters.

Comment: @Barmar i try to put in UTF-8, Latin-1 and nothing..

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the code that created the file, so it doesn't have any valid encoding.

Comment: @Barmar the source file is stay in "ANSI"

Comment: That's not an encoding.

Comment: 0x8d is not used in the ANSI character set

Comment: @Pingu how to encoding this?

Comment: Do you mean extended ASCII?

Comment: @CrazyChucky i have not idea

Comment: Are you sure you tried *encoding='latin-1'* because that will decode 0x8d It may have problems with other data but not that particular value

Comment: @Pingu ok, i will try again

Comment: @Pingu this is the error with latin-1


UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9a' in position 56: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Do you know what language the text is likely to be? That might give a clue. Also, the filename has a pattern seen on mainframes (apart from the .txt extension) in which case you could try cp037 or cp437

Comment: @Pingu exactly is from a mainframe, it's Adabas the database

Comment: Take a look here:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: @Pingu i don't know how to apply that...